# Wait for app to finish initialization before changing route

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

When I start my app I have an initialization process that shows some loading indicator and shows the actual content after everything is loaded. Now when I change the Url manually, the initialization process is also triggered, which is good, but the view controller assigned to that route is also created and starts its work right away before the initialization is completed. I tried to use a resolve property at my routes, where I return a promise that is resolved once the app is loaded, however I put this promise in a service and thats forbidden to be injected during the config phase.

How can I wait for the app to be completely loaded before I change the route?